# s_sess cookie not storing the value from query string parameter cid

Tags: session-cookies, aem, adobe-analytics, web-analytics

Does anyone has any information about s_sess cookie. All I can find is that it's a performance cookie.

The issue here is : My client has 2 websites, one of them is storing the value of query string parameter "cid" in s_sess cookie while the other site is not. Both of them has same adobe analytics code and both sites are on third party cookies.

Comment: Analytics code is normally bound to a single site, are you sharing same config in both unique sites (i.e. with different URLs)? Analytics accounts may be restricted to particular site(s) so can you check your config?

Comment: Cookies created by `s.c_w()` and `s.Util.cookieWrite()` are always first-party. They are separate to the visitor cookie from your DCS. Try putting new values in the `cid` querystring on each site and see what happens.

Answer (score 4):

Many of Adobe's plugins make use of the `s.c_r()` and `s.c_w()` (legacy H code) or `s.Util.cookieRead()` and `s.Util.cookieWrite()` (AppMeasurement) functions, which are for reading/writing cookies, respectively. Out of the box, you specify a cookie name and it writes to that cookie namespace.

However, Adobe also has a "combined" cookie plugin. With this plugin, all cookie reading/writing with the above functions are instead written to one of two cookies:

- `s_sess` - This cookie is for **sess**ion scoped "cookies"
- `s_pers` - This cookie is for "cookies" that **pers**ist longer than session

So for example, let's say on the following page:

`http://www.yoursite.com/index.html?cid=some_code`

And in your AA code, you have the following:

```
// look for cid= param to put into campaign variable
s.campaign = s.Util.getQueryParam('cid');
// use getValOnce plugin to make sure duplicate values do not pop it again
s.campaign = s.getValOnce(s.campaign, 'cid', 0);
```

*Without* the combined cookies function, you will see a cookie named "cid" in `document.cookies` with value of "some_code" set to expire on Session.

But with the combined cookies function, you will not see a cookie named "cid". Instead, you will see a cookie named "s_sess" with a value like this:

```
// encoded
%20cid=some_code%3B
// unencoded
 cid=some_code;
```

Or, if you use a plugin that makes use of `s.c_w` or `s.Util.cookieWrite` for longer than Session, you will instead see the `s_pers` cookie populated the same way, but with a timestamp value thrown into the mix, e.g.

```
// encoded
%20cid=some_code%7C1519759520136%3B
// unencoded
 cid=some_code|1519759520136;
```

Multiple "cookies" are separated by (unencoded) "; " (similar to `document.cookie`)

**But why do I see it on one site but not the other?**

Assuming your implementation is in fact identical, my guess based on what you posted vs. common implementations is you have code similar to my example above: You grab cid= param for campaign tracking and make use of `getValOnce` or some other plugin that pushes the value to a cookie, and you went to siteA page with a campaign code (cid= param) but not siteB.

Comment: Thanks for your response. 
1.)My client's both sites are on 1.7 version of s_code.js (appmeasurement code), 
2.)Both sites are on v1.10.0 of visitor API.js, 
3.)Both are on third party cookies

Comment: Code Used for both Web properties (sites):

s.campaign = s.getValOnce(s.campaign,"cid_cookie", 0);

The plugin s_sess and s_pers is also implemented for both web properties custom code.

Everything is exactly same still for one site ,query string parameter value cid is getting stored in s_sess while for the other it doesn't.

Can there be any thing related to AEM here as both sites were stroing the value a month prior and all of a sudden, one site has stopped capturing query string 'cid' value in s_sess cookie.

Comment: p.s. There were no DTM changes made from adobe analytics end (Verified complete history for published changes)

Comment: @Pankaj-WebAnalyticsLead Perhaps your `s.campaign = ...` code is wrapped in some other logic, like maybe channel manager plugin stuff?
  So maybe the code isn't being executed depending on _how_ you get to the page with the campaign code? Without being able to look at your sites more deeply myself, all I can do is stand by what I already said in my post